# append items to array by their name with for loop and format inside function

Tags: python

I'm trying to append items to an array by their name.
here is my code:

```
def create_filters(_shapes):
"""create masked filters to use on the image."""
  row, col = _shapes
  row, col  = int(row/2), int(col/2)
  urow, drow = row+10, row-10
  ucol, dcol = col+10, col-10

  masks = []
  mask1 = np.ones(_shapes, np.uint16)
  mask1[:,dcol:ucol] = 0
  # masks.append(mask1)
  mask2 = np.ones(_shapes, np.uint16)
  mask2[drow:urow,:] = 0
  # masks.append(mask2)
  mask3 = cv.bitwise_not(mask1)
  # masks.append(mask3)
  mask4 = cv.bitwise_not(mask2)
  # masks.append(mask4)
  mask5 = np.zeros(_shapes, np.uint16)
  mask5[drow:urow,dcol:ucol] = 255
  # masks.append(mask5)
  mask6 = cv.bitwise_not(mask5)
  # masks.append(mask6)
  mask7 = np.copy(mask1)
  mask7[drow:urow,:] = 0
  # masks.append(mask7)
  mask8 = cv.bitwise_not(mask7) 
  # masks.append(mask8)

  for i in range(1,9):
      m = globals()[f'mask{i}']
      masks.append(m)

  return masks
```

so basically I want to append all mask1-8 to masks. Now, since mask1-8 are **local** variables I can't use global().
Is there a better way to do it? I know I can initialize the array like that:

```
masks=[mask1, mask2,...]
```

but I'm asking specifically for using string as the variable name in a for loop.

Comment: Just define them after with the variable names, there isn't really any need to do this as a for loop

Comment: here I got only 8 filters, what happened if I got 100? define each? @Sayse

Comment: Why don't you use `locals()`?

Comment: But you don't have 100, you do have 8. If you had 100 then i'd hope you'd try to come up with some better logic to create the list

Comment: You can just iterate over range(n) - where n=8 or 100 or whatever - and append directly to the list.

Comment: you right, but I did it just to learn something which I learned now, thnx, @Sayse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to cut this, but to address your specific question:

As per my comment, you can simply use `locals()` in place of `globals()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `eval` i.e:

```py
for i in range(1,9):
    m = eval(f"mask{i}")
    masks.append(m)
```

The eval-function parses and evaluates any python expression using the global and local namespaces. See the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) for more information on eval.